# Conditional Number Percentage Styling iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, percentage

I'm trying to display a percentage label that will have some style based on its value.  A user gets likes and dislikes.  These totals are displayed in the totalLikesLabel and totalDislikesLabel.

I want the approvalPercentageLabel to display the Percentage of likes to dislikes. Above 50% the text will show green, below 50% the text will show red.

When I log the [self.totalLikesLabel.text intValue] and [self.totalDislikesLabel.text intValue] they appear as 22 and 12.  When they are both currently set to 1.

@interface

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *totalLikesLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *totalDislikesLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *approvalPercentageLabel;

@property (nonatomic) int likeCount;
@property (nonatomic) int dislikeCount;
```

-viewDidLoad

```
self.likeCount = [self.totalLikesLabel.text intValue];
self.dislikeCount = [self.totalDislikesLabel.text intValue];

float approvalPercentage = (self.likeCount / (self.likeCount + self.dislikeCount)) * 100.0;
self.approvalPercentageLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.0f%%", approvalPercentage];
```

-helperMethod

```
//Create an Array to check either user photo
NSArray *userPhotos = @[self.firstUserPhoto, self.secondUserPhoto];

PFQuery *queryForLikes = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kDDActivityClassKey];
[queryForLikes whereKey:kDDActivityTypeKey equalTo:kDDActivityTypeLikeKey];
[queryForLikes whereKey:kDDActivityFirstUserPhotoKey containedIn:userPhotos];
[queryForLikes whereKey:kDDActivitySecondUserPhotoKey containedIn:userPhotos];
[queryForLikes countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int number, NSError *error) {
    self.totalLikesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", number];
    NSLog(@"Likes %i", number);
}];

PFQuery *queryForDislikes = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kDDActivityClassKey];
[queryForDislikes whereKey:kDDActivityTypeKey equalTo:kDDActivityTypeDislikeKey];
[queryForDislikes whereKey:kDDActivityFirstUserPhotoKey containedIn:userPhotos];
[queryForDislikes whereKey:kDDActivitySecondUserPhotoKey containedIn:userPhotos];
[queryForDislikes countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int number, NSError *error) {
    self.totalDislikesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", number];
    NSLog(@"Dislikes %i", number);
}];
```

Comment: I think your math is off. It should be `(totalLikes / (totalLikes + totalDislikes))*100` and similar for the total dislikes. The way it is at the moment is if 50 people like and 50 people dislike it'll be 100% total approval.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up added this query to the helper method.  I'm getting a Warning: A long-running Parse operation is being executed on the main thread so that's not ideal but otherwise it's working.

```
PFQuery *queryForApprovalPercent = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[queryForLikes, queryForDislikes]];
[queryForApprovalPercent countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int number, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        [queryForLikes countObjects];
        self.likeCount = [queryForLikes countObjects];
        self.dislikeCount = [queryForDislikes countObjects];
        float approvalPercentage = (self.likeCount / (self.likeCount + self.dislikeCount)) * 100.0;
        self.approvalPercentageLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.0f%%", approvalPercentage];
        if (approvalPercentage < 5) self.approvalPercentageLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
}];
```